# локальные переменные vs поля класса

Tags: java, ооп

Хотелось бы понять вот на таком простом примере: я пишу класс GUI. Мне нужно добавить на него JTabbedPane. Я создаю метод и добавляю

```
private void createTabbedPane() {
    MyTabbedPane taskTabbedPane = new MyTabbedPane();
    taskTabbedPane.addTab("Задача",
            createTasksMainInfoPanel(taskTabbedPane));
    taskTabbedPane.addTab("Данные", null);
    taskTabbedPane.setEnabledAt(1, false);
}
```

как видно в этой строке:

```
taskTabbedPane.addTab("Задача",
            createTasksMainInfoPanel(taskTabbedPane));
```

я вызываю еще один метод, которому требуется JTabbedPane и передаю туда только что созданную JTabbedPane как параметр. И так она у меня и передается по цепочке, потому что нужна во многих методах. У меня вопрос: нужно ли делать этот JTabbedPane полем класса GUI? С одной стороны это поможет избавить методы от лишних параметров. С другой стороны - у меня и с другими компонентами такая ситуация. Не будет ли ошибкой создавать так много полей класса? Ведь объект этого класса будет занимать очень много места в памяти?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Само поле по себе не занимает много места (формально - это просто ссылка, а это 4-8 байт. я конечно могу ошибаться, но не думаю, что там более 20 байт).

В жаве не принято экономить такую мелкую память.

Передача локальной переменной - это также трата памяти и передавая постоянно с метода в метод, можно потратить "больше", чем если просто сделать поле класса.

---

Но если присмотреться, то сильно похоже, что у Вас есть целая пачка методов, которые занимаются созданием вкладки. И получается, что в этом классе смешано две разные сущности - основные методы класса и методы для создания вкладки. Поэтому правильно будет создать "билдер" - построитель - отельный класс, который умеет создавать и настраивать вкладку.

Тогда основной код будет выглядеть где то так (тут используются разные построители для разных вкладок. Эти два класса будут наследоваться от одного базового)

```
private void createTabbedPane() {
    MainTabBuilder.addTab(taskTabbedPane, "Задача");
    VoidTabBuilder.addTab(taskTabbedPane, "Данные");
    taskTabbedPane.setEnabledAt(1, false);
}
```

или так (тут передаем третий параметр, который определяет, что создать)

```
private void createTabbedPane() {
    TabBuilder.addTab(taskTabbedPane, "Задача", TabBuilder.Main);
    TabBuilder.addTab(taskTabbedPane, "Данные", TabBuilder.Void);
    taskTabbedPane.setEnabledAt(1, false);
}
```

или так (тут разные методы одного класса)

```
private void createTabbedPane() {
    TabBuilder.addMainTab(taskTabbedPane, "Задача");
    TabBuilder.addVoidTab(taskTabbedPane, "Данные");
    taskTabbedPane.setEnabledAt(1, false);
}
```

Скорее всего этим методам понадобиться ещё один параметр, в котором будут храниться данные для создания вкладки.

В моем примере методы построителя выглядят статическими, но это дело вкуса, внутри может создаваться объект.

Внутри построителя переменная, которая содержит ссылку на создаваемый таб будет формально самой главной и скорее всего будет полем класса.

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ! Я только одного не понял. Вот вы пишите: " И получается, что в этом классе смешано две разные сущности - основные методы класса и методы для создания вкладки". А есть какой-то способ отличить где основные методы а где не основные? Ведь вкладка - это основной компонент на моем GUI. Почему методы, в котором она создается нельзя считать основными?

Comment: это очень философский вопрос, какие методы где должны быть и Вы вполне можете не согласиться со мной. Лично я вижу в данной задаче как минимум три сущности - создание вкладки, решение задачи и код, который это все связывает.

Нет никаких особых правил, что бы уметь выделять, это придет со временем.

Comment: да, все так и есть, только задач еще больше: еще создаются разные панели, отдельные окно, меню. Попробую для всего этого сделать билдеров

Comment: тут главное не переусердствовать. Если для какого то кода 3-5 строк, то вряд ли нужно сразу брать и выносить.

Иногда вместо одного большого "супер-класса" появляется сотни мелких классов и ещё не понятно, что лучше.

Comment: правильно я понял что в случае с отрисовкой панелей - это скорее дело вкуса. Но вот, например с кнопками. Я создал наследника JButton в котором в конструкторе прописал setFocusable(false) и setToolTipText("some text"). Если бы я этого не сделал то для каждой кнопки пришлось писать бы это в основном классе. То как я сделал помогает ведь устранить дублирование кода, правильно?

Comment: а если разделять на много классов, то появится проблема большого количества связей между классами, так ведь?

Answer (score 2):

Если созданный объект `taskTabbedPane` нигде кроме этого метода не используется, то нет никакого смысла засорять определение класса членами, которые используются лишь в качестве локальных переменных отдельных методов.

Каждая переменная должна иметь наименьшую область видимости там, где она используется и не должна существовать там, где она не используется.